# SSAS Max date in grouped set of records

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have a query where I need to pull back the latest risk assessment rating for a record, but need to do this for all records from the query. I have `MS SSRS Report Builder (V3)` as the only way to access this data and no access to modify the underlying cubes which are provided by a supplier.

My basic MDX which pulls out the data needed is the following:

```
SELECT 

NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[No of Investigations] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { (
[Investigation Indicators and Text Fields].[Investigation Reference Number].[Investigation Reference Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Risk Assessment Rating].[Risk Rating].[Risk Rating].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Risk Assessment Completed Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Risk Assessment Completed Time].[Time HHMM].[Time HHMM].ALLMEMBERS 
) } ON ROWS 

FROM [Investigation]
```

which leaves my Date and Time needing to be concatenated. I have carried this out as a calculated field but am unable to then test for a max value as it gives me an error around using an aggregate function.

Is anyone able to provide me with any ideas on how to carry this out, either via the `MDX` statement or subsequently. Ideally I would like to be able to create the results in two ways - one with all records and a marker showing which is the latest assessment, and one which just pulls back the subset via `MDX`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "for a record"? Do you mean "for a customer"? If so, how is your customer hierarchy named? Is it correct to assume that `Investigation Reference Number` and `Risk Rating` are just attributes of each single risk assessment. This means the question is "For each customer, I want to see that latest date/time when a risk assessment happened, and the  `Investigation Reference Number` and `Risk Rating` of that rating." Are any measures relevant at all? I am not sure why you use `No of Investigations` here, this does not seem to contribute anything to the answer.

Comment: On the source system Investigations are the core records, and linked to these we have People, Locations and other Objects which includes Risk Assessments. Each investigation can have multiple risk assessments, and these can be of multiple different types. These are date/time stamped and as such we generally need to pull back the latest one but may also need to be able to view the change of these over time.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is "For each customer, I want to see that latest date/time when a risk assessment happened, and the Investigation Reference Number and Risk Rating of that rating." the correct description of your requirement?

Comment: Almost - no customers in my world - everything is against the Investigation record. So to put it simply I would like the Investigation Reference Number and the latest Risk Rating against this.

Comment: Thus an investigation reference number can have several ratings and completed dates/times?

Comment: Precisely - to make it worse we can have multiple types of assessments but I ignoring that for now!

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested) Interested to know if this helps?

```
WITH SET [X] AS
  TAIL(
    NONEMPTY(
      {[Risk Assessment Completed Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
       [Risk Assessment Completed Time].[Time HHMM].[Time HHMM].ALLMEMBERS}
     ,{([Measures].[No of Investigations])} 
    )
  )
SELECT 

NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[No of Investigations] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { (
  [Investigation Indicators and Text Fields].[Investigation Reference Number].[Investigation     Reference Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
  [Risk Assessment Rating].[Risk Rating].[Risk Rating].ALLMEMBERS * 
  [X]
) } ON ROWS 

FROM [Investigation]
```

Comment: Just tested this and it brings back a single record against all my Investigations - I do not think I was clear in my original post (apologies) but I need to end up with the latest Risk Assessment for each Investigation, rather than just the most recent against all Risk Assessments. Ideally I would still like to return the records where there is no Risk Assessment as the blanks, and the percentage of missing records, represent an important set of records which need to be accessed for quality assurance.

Comment: yes - a custom set won't be "context aware" of what you have selected - apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
SELECT 

NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[No of Investigations] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY
[Investigation Indicators and Text Fields].[Investigation Reference Number].[Investigation Reference Number].ALLMEMBERS
*
Tail(
     NonEmpty(
              [Risk Assessment Completed Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
              *
              [Risk Assessment Completed Time].[Time HHMM].[Time HHMM].MEMBERS
              ,
              { [Investigation Indicators and Text Fields].[Investigation Reference Number].CurrentMember }
        )
    )
}
*  
[Risk Assessment Rating].[Risk Rating].[Risk Rating].ALLMEMBERS
ON ROWS 

FROM [Investigation]
```

should deliver what you want.

The `NonEmpty(...)` is the set of all Date/time combinations that have data for the current investigation reference number. By using `Members` instead of `AllMembers`, I excluded calculated date/time members, which normally would sort at the end, assuming there are none that you would need. Assuming all non-calculated date and time members are sorted chronologically, we just can take the set containing the last tuple of this set, which is what `Tail` does.

Finally, we use all risk ratings which appear with this reference number, date, and time, which hopefully is only one.

Comment: Apologies for the very slow response to this - this method still produces only single result, the max value across the whole cube rather than the max value for each Reference Number. Is there something which can be tweaked to run within each subset of assessments against each Reference Number?